# Button within fragment, refreshes/reloads all fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is killing me. I have one DemoFragment which has 3 instances created. Within these instances different data is loaded into the fragments. What I want to be able to do is have a button (within the fragment) that forces all of the Fragments to refresh or reload. This is necessary as the button also commits new data that needs to be pulled newly for every fragment.

I've search plenty of solutions, but can't get to the bottom of it. Currently I have a an activity, fragment and adapter. Below is the abridged code (as expected this loads 3 pages):

**Activity (RoutineDetailsActivity.java)**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;


public class RoutineDetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager mViewPager;
Button mLogout;
CustomPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_routine_details);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    }
}
```

**Adapter (CustomPagerAdapter.java)**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.Locale;

public class CustomPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

public CustomPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return DemoFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
    }
}
```

**Fragment (DemoFragment.java)**

```
public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {

int mNum;

static DemoFragment newInstance(int num) {
    DemoFragment f = new DemoFragment();

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_routine_details, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    // CODE CLIPPED, do loads of sh*t
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // New data uploaded to server
                        // What code to force reload the fragments?
                    }
                });
}
```

So within this code, more specifically, within the button click, what do I need to do to force the all Fragments to reload and retrieve the latest data.

I've sen answers around this, but I'm sure how to relate it to here.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm tempting to say that you could implement a `Broadcast` that would spread through the `Fragments`...

Comment: @shkschneider what holds you back from saying that?

Comment: Nothing, that was just an idea. At least that's how I'm doing a lot of multi-fragment updates.

Comment: @shkschneider sounds good to me aswell. I am using EventBus to avoid some of the boilerplate code tied to using broadcasts, plus making it possible to send arbitrary complex objects around. The idea is basically still the same though.

Comment: In the app RoutineDetailsActivity.java (the activity) loads from another activity, is there no way I can simply force it to do that again. Or is that really bad practice? Anymore info on how the broadcast would work? My assumption was that putting the code in the onResume would force it to reload the data, however I've noticed the onResume doesn't work always when sliding between the fragments.

Answer (score 2):

If you a willing to add a small library called EventBus: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

You can do like this:

```
public class AnyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onAttach(final Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void onEventMainThread(UpdateUIEvent ev) {
        // perform refresh
    }
}
```

UpdateUIEvent is just a simple empty object in my case but could contain arbitrary data as well:

```
public class UpdateUIEvent {}
```

With this in place you can refresh AnyFragment from anywhere in your code by doing:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new UpdateUIEvent());
```

I want to stress that you can do this **Anywhere**, but in you case, the above line would be the only thing you would have to do in click of your button. Then all fragments listening, as shown with `AnyFragment`, will receive the event :)

Comment: Doesn't seem to do any thing, but then again I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. So I've put the code into the DemoFragment as mentioned, setup the empty object, put EventBus.getDefault().post(new UpdateUIEvent()); into my button action. Nothing happens, I tried to place a function into where you've got the comment //perform refresh, nothing happens.

Comment: I do not see the methods from my example AnyFragment in your DemoFragment. You need to have onAttatch,  onDetatch and onEventMainThread

Comment: I added the first bit of code just below public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {... (removing the original public class AnyFragment). 

Then added the third extract of code in the button listener, as well as adding the public class UpdateUIEvent. I haven't added to the code above just so anyone looking at it can see the original code.

Comment: I am getting uncertain whether you might have to add EventBus.getDefault().register(this) to onCreate of your Activity. Please give it a try.

Comment: Correction: If it is necessary to register the parent Activity, you should do `EventBus.getDefault().register(this)` in `onResume()` and `EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)` in `onPause()`

Comment: I tried adding in those bits of code directly below where each state occurs, however it crashes the app. First part of error is:

01-09 12:19:49.238  11883-11883/com.blah.sevenweekstrainer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blah.sevenweekstrainer, PID: 11883
    de.greenrobot.event.EventBusException: Subscriber class com.blah.sevenweekstrainer.DemoFragment already registered to event class com.blah.sevenweekstrainer.UpdateUIEvent

Comment: For now I've done it probably a really ugly way, which is simply to send an intent for the parent activity carrying over the extras again. Are there any drawbacks?

Comment: It is probably ok, I would just wish that EventBus had worked cause it is great in so many other scenarios. If what you do is working, it is probably ok. Perhaps consider using LocalBroadcast if you aren't already.

Answer (score 0):

Implement an interface in your fragment say `IRefresher`. Keep track of references of the 3 fragments in your activity. When button is clicked call the interface method say `refreshMe()` which would work as a listener/callback in the fragments and in that method refresh your fragment.

I have done it in one of my project and it works flawlessly

Comment: This will be a terrible work for OP, as he would then have to 1) keep the references in his Activity 2) call the activity on button click (yet another method to add besides the interface/refresh methods in each fragmen. In my opinion an unnecessarily high coupling of code. Broadcasts or EventBus is the way to go, atleast IMO.

Comment: Gave an idea what worked for me. But I had to refresh only one fragment at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I have understood your problem or not. From your button trigger you can call the parent activity which one is holding all the fragments. Create a method in the parent activity. Inside the method register listener (Call Interface method) which update the fragments lists. Call the parent method from fragment(s) when you need it.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, do you have an example of something similar. How would I specifically call the parent activity and ask for the update?